# How can I store / download the recording from the Screen Capture web API?

Tags: javascript, screen-capture, mediastream, get-display-media

I'm using the [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) and am trying to save the final capture to a video file (WebM, MP4, etc.). I have these two JavaScript functions:

```
async function startCapture() {
    try {
      videoElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error("Error: " + err);
    }
}

function stopCapture() {
    let tracks = videoElem.srcObject.getTracks();
    tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
    videoElem.srcObject = null;
}
```

The video is displaying live fine when the capture is started, but I'm not sure how to actually store its contents. `videoElem` is a `Promise` that resolves to a `MediaStream`. `tracks` is an array of `MediaStreamTrack` objects. This is my first time doing any kind of web development, so I'm a bit lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recording a media element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element) on the MDN docs helped me a ton. Basically, instead of using `getUserMedia()`, we use `getDisplayMedia()`.

Answer (score 5):

```
async function startRecording() {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true
});
recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

const chunks = [];
recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
recorder.onstop = e => {
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: chunks[0].type });
    console.log(blob);
    stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();

    filename="yourCustomFileName"
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else{
        var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        elem.download = filename;        
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();        
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
    };
    recorder.start();
}
startRecording(); //Start of the recording 

-----------

recorder.stop() // End your recording by emitting this event
```

**This will save your recording as a webm file**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any workaround to make it work on Mac OS ?

Comment: thanks for this. This really saved me in my thesis

Answer (score 0):

Like with any MediaStream, you can record it using the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder).